# Double Bond Geometry

Tags: molecular-structure

The double bond at position '4' appears to be showing a 'E' geometry because the priority 1's are on opposite sides of the double bond ie top-left of bond4 is '1' (because Oxygen > Carbon)); bottom-left of bond4 is '2'; top-right of bond4 is '2' and bottom-right of bond4 is '1'(because it has more carbons than the other side).
I am unable to see why 'Z' is the correct geometry.
Appreciate any suggestions.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: Welcome to ChemSE!  The tetrasubstituted double bond is E (CH2OH>CH3CH2 and CH=CHCH3>CH3CH2). The disubstituted double bond is Z (C4>H and CH3>H). BTW: Your numbering is incorrect. The actual name is (2E,4Z)-2,3-diethylhexa-2,4-dien-1-ol. The cmpd. is an alcohol.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and response. Appreciated.